# How to prove this integral equation?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$$\left( \frac{z^n}{n!}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{z^n e^{z\zeta}}{n!\zeta^n}\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta}.$$
Where C is a simple closed curve around the origin. First, calculate on the right side, I can get
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{ e^{z\zeta}}{\zeta^n}\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}\frac{1}{\zeta^{n-k}}\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{1}{\zeta^{n-k}}\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta}.$$
Then I don't know how to use Cauchy's integral formula to calculate $\int_{C}\frac{1}{\zeta^{n-k}}\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta}$.

BTW, I don't know how to calculate this integral:
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{(z-1)^n(z-3)}.$$
They seem to be using the same method.Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use the residue theorem (or symmetry for a simpler way) to get that $\int_C\frac{1}{\zeta^{n-k}\zeta}d\zeta=0$ if $n-k+1\not=1$ and $2\pi i$ otherwise.

Comment: Thank you, i got it.@VarunVejalla

Comment: No need to expand the exponential.  Since $e^{z\zeta}$ is analytic in $\zeta$, we may apply the residue method directly to $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{C}\frac{z^n e^{z\zeta}}{n!\zeta^n}\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta}$.

Comment: Where did the factor of $z^k/k!$ go in the second line of equations?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider the function $f(\zeta)=z^ne^{\zeta z}$ and apply Cauchy’s integral formula for derivatives. As you can see, the integral you have to calculate is equal to $2\pi i f^{(n)}(0)/n!$. After this you should see the result. The formula you are seeking is this:

$f^{(n)}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{C} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_0)^{n+1}}d\zeta$